# Display all images in a directory to a list in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I was wondering if there is a way i can display all images or files in a particular directory located in user's mobile device to a list/array in flutter so i can use in a ListView.

Thanks any help is welcomed.

PS: i wanted to try with path_provider but didn't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

I had to work with [MethodChannels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) in other to achieve this.

After writing the java code for getting the file list, i passed in into flutter through a channel

Java Method for getting files

```
private List<String> getImages(){
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        List<String> imgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        File directory = new File(path);
        List<String> files = Arrays.asList(directory.list());

        imgs = files;

        return imgs;
    }
```

Java MethodChannel

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
              (call, result) -> {
                  if (call.method.equals("getImages")) {
                      List<String> imgs = getImages();
                      if (imgs.size() <= 0) {
                          result.error("Empty", "No Images.", null);
                      } else {
                          result.success(imgs);                      }
                  } else {
                      result.notImplemented();
                  }

              });
```

Dart Code

```
 Future<void> _getImages() async {
    List images;
    try {
      final List result = await platform.invokeMethod('getImages');
      images = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Error");
    }

    setState(() {
      imgs = images;
    });
  }
```

Full Source Code available on [Github](https://github.com/JideGuru/wa_status)

Comment: there is a problem with the getImages() it would return all the files URL other than images also from the directory

Answer (score 7):

I am working on application that uses local storage / application directory.

After spending five days I got a solution...

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final Directory _photoDir = new Directory(
    '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.eclixtech.doc_scanner/files/CroppedImages');

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Document Scanner',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ImageCapture(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageCapture extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _ImageCaptureState createState() => _ImageCaptureState();
}

class _ImageCaptureState extends State<ImageCapture> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Doc Scanner'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, status) {
            return ImageGrid(directory: _photoDir);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class ImageGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final Directory directory;

  const ImageGrid({Key key, this.directory}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var refreshGridView;
    var imageList = directory
        .listSync()
        .map((item) => item.path)
        .where((item) => item.endsWith(".jpg"))
        .toList(growable: false);
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: imageList.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3, childAspectRatio: 3.0 / 4.6),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        File file = new File(imageList[index]);
        String name = file.path.split('/').last;
        return Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => {
                refreshGridView =
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return ImageEditClass(
                imagepath: imageList[index],
              );
            })).then((refreshGridView) {
              if (refreshGridView != null) {
                build(context);
              }
            }).catchError((er) {
              print(er);
            }),
              },
               child: Padding(
                 padding: new EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                 child: Image.file(
                   File(imageList[index]),
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                 ),
               ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can mention the extention(.jpg, .png ect) of images here.

```
.where((item) => item.endsWith(".jpg"))
```

in above mentioned code.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar to that, In one of my flutter Application, i am getting the list of the images Urls from downloads directory and showing them in staggered list.

Retrieving of images URLs from the downloads directory is done with the help of MethodChannel. Also, don't forget to add the required package to pubspec.yaml file in flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:denphy_wallpapers/main_image_screen/fullscreen_wallpaper.dart';

class Downloads extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'downloads';

  @override
  _DownloadsState createState() => _DownloadsState();
}

class _DownloadsState extends State<Downloads> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');
  List images;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _getImages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          "Downloads",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Welcome', color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 32.0),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: images != null
          ? new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                String imgPath = images[i];
                print(imgPath);
                return new Material(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  child: new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //print(imageName);
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  new FullScreenImagePage(imgPath, "")));
                    },
                    child: new Hero(
                      tag: imgPath,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          child: Image.file(
                            File(imgPath),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (i) =>
                  new StaggeredTile.count(2, i.isEven ? 2 : 3),
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            )
          : new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
    );
  }

  //Check the MainActivity.java
  Future<void> _getImages() async {
    print('inside get images>>>>>>>>>>>>');
    List imgs;
    try {
      final List result = await platform.invokeMethod('getImages');
      imgs = result;
      for (String i in result) {
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>$i');
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Error");
    }

    setState(() {
      images = imgs;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the code for MainActivity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;

import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                         if(call.method.equals("getImages")){
                            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onMethodCall: "+"get Images" );
                            List<String> imgs = getImages();
                            if (imgs.size() <= 0) {
                                result.error("Empty", "No Images.", null);
                            } else {
                                result.success(imgs);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }


    private List<String> getImages() {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()+"/denphy walls/");
        folder.mkdirs();
        File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".png"));
            }
        });
        List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : allFiles) {
            item.add(file + "");
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

The above code contains some extra functionality you can remove them as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` which fetchs values from appication storage.

```
Future<String> get _getLocalPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = directory.path;
    final String filePath = '$path/folderName/';
    return filePath;
  }
```

`FileSystemEntity`, provides the file path, which can be used to show images.

```
    String _localPath = await _getLocalPath;
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
    List<FileSystemEntity> files = savedDir.listSync(); /// iterate the list to get individual entry.
```