# Flutter show date of image when picking an image

Tags: flutter, dart, uiimagepickercontroller, imagepicker

I implemented the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) inside my app and it is working just fine. However I would like to have a certain feature:

[image]

I found this on the [Once Upon App](https://onceupon.photo/de-de). As you can see in the screenshot  you can **choose a Month** and also **see the specific date with day**. I need that exact feature in my app but I couldn't find anything on how to do this in Flutter.

Does anyone know a way to get this done? My app is for iOS and Android only. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: So the `image_picker` plugin uses the native UI to show the picker. From what I understand you need to show a custom picker.

To achieve this, you have two possible routes:

1. native route: using a native library for each platform which involves you writing platform channels to integrate it or creating your own native UI to match the picture in the question.
2. flutter route: using platform channels to get the list of images somehow and show them in this custom UI in the Flutter app, not a native dialog.

i am not really sure if on iOS you can get a list of photos but there should be

Comment: @YazeedAlKhalaf I thought of the 2nd way as well but couldn't find a way to get all the photos and even more important: Get the createdDate of all the images :/

Comment: i see what is the problem now, i know this might take time but did you try talking to the developer of the app that has the functionality you need? maybe they can help.

Comment: @YazeedAlKhalaf I will do that :D but I think the app is build with native code ..

Comment: Yea no problem, you need to write some native code to get the functionality anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [native_exif](https://pub.dev/packages/native_exif) to fetch the date of creation. Create a list of images based on date of creation and add date placeholders between 2 different days and sort it based on the date selected.

Comment: But how do I get all the images ?

Comment: You can use platform channels to get all images from the device, Image picker can also work but depends on your requirement. Are you looking to import all images from gallery and sort them based on dates?

Comment: Yes kind of, the user should pick an image but the UI should be like the one above so the users sees and can select the date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692052/display-all-images-in-a-directory-to-a-list-in-flutter. Try this one

Comment: how exactly would I get the date of an image with the above mentioned package? Could you give me an example? And also, getting also images on iOS and Android would still be a problem...